# Can I Get Referrer Info if "referer" is Empty Due to rel="noopener" on the Link?

Tags: javascript, iis, http-headers, http-referer, server-variables

I observed some cases where a website would receive empty referrer information if the external link the user clicked on had the `rel="noopener` attribute.

To summarize what I am seeing:

- the server variable `HTTP_REFERER` (the `Referer` HTTP header) is empty, due to...
- `rel="noopener` being set on the source link.

I am 100% sure it is the `rel="noopener` causing the empty referrer, because when I use chrome dev tools to remove the attribute on the source link, then click it, the `HTTP_REFERER` value shows up correctly on the server side.

Is there any way I can still get ANY referrer information in this scenario even if it is just the root domain of the referring page?

The site runs on IIS 8.5, and I can accommodate a solution in `javascript`, `jquery`, `vbscript`, or `classic asp 3.0`, but I am open to any and all suggestions.

I have looked at the many other questions about getting referrer when the `Referer` header is empty, but none of them are specifically about when `rel="noopener` is the root cause of it being empty, and none of them provide an answer specific to this, well, specific question.

Comment: See https://mathiasbynens.github.io/rel-noopener/ - there are some workarounds but most of them won't work. So no, I think there's no way really

Comment: Well seems like if you could it would be a bug in the browser

Comment: @MattFletcher - Unless I missed it, that URL you posted doesn't have any suggestions for retrieving the referrer when noopener is used.

Comment: No but it explains that what you're trying to do is the _very reason_ why `noopener` even exists in the first place. It would be pretty poor if you could get around it. I admittedly misread the article and thought it was saying there were workarounds for older browsers.

Comment: @epascarello - I know. It feels like not having the referrer info is a side-effect of trying to solve that security problem of the new window having control of the original window... to me they should be separated. It feels like in solving that security issue, it also breaks a feature i.e. passing referrer info. Logically, shouldn't only `noreferrer` prevent the referrer? Why does `noopener` have to also prevent the referrer?